# MySQL: Key/value store queries optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, store, key-value

I am seeking a help with setting up **correct indexes** (i've tried too many and now i am a bit lost), **correct MySQL engine** (MyIsam, InnoDB...) and help with **my queries** (JOINs, ...). Also I have headache when I am thinking that these queries should return **count(*)**.

My times were more than 5 - 10 seconds per query without counting, but I am not sure if I can get better times for this big database.

I am trying to optimize this MySQL tables:

**Items (~600k rows):**

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type  | varchar(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Items_Relationships (~1M rows):**

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| lft_item_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rgt_item_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rel_type    | varchar(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Items_Values (~4M rows):**

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
| name    | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value   | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lang    | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am running basically these common queries:

**1. query - All items with value "status" > 1:**

```
SELECT `company`.`id` AS `id`,
       `company`.`type` AS `type`
FROM `items` AS `company`
INNER JOIN `items_values` AS `value_name` ON (`company`.`id` = `value_name`.`item_id`)
WHERE `company`.`type` = 'company'
  AND `value_name`.`name` = 'status'
  AND CONVERT(`value_name`.`value`, SIGNED) > 1 
GROUP BY `company`.`id`
ORDER BY `company`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

**2. query - All items with some values in relationship with other items:**

```
SELECT `company`.`id` AS `id`,
       `company`.`type` AS `type`
FROM `items` AS `company`
INNER JOIN `items_values` AS `value_status` ON (`value_status`.`item_id` = `company`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `items_relationships` AS `companies_categories` ON (`companies_categories`.`lft_item_id` = `company`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `items_values` AS `category_rgt` ON (`category_rgt`.`item_id` = `companies_categories`.`rgt_item_id`)
WHERE `company`.`type` = 'company'
  AND `company`.`type` = 'company'
  AND `value_status`.`name` = 'status'
  AND CONVERT(`value_status`.`value`, SIGNED) >= 1
  AND `category_rgt`.`name` = 'rgt'
  AND (CONVERT(category_rgt.value, UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 2805 AND 4222)
  AND `companies_categories`.`rel_type` = 'company_category'
GROUP BY `company`.`id`
ORDER BY `company`.`id` DESC LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: Key-value stores are notoriously clumsy to code for, and do not scale.  Here is a blog on what to do instead.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Comment: Look really usefull, but I have to read it more times to be clear.. If we have this solution with examples would help me to understand better..

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about indexes, so you have almost everything you need already indexed.

I have just question about

`| name    | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |`

So I would prefer to set it as well as primary key.

I have only one suggestion about table structures.

If you have mixed string and numbers in your

`| value   | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |`

create another column `int_value SIGNED` or unsigned is even better.

And you should set that column as index as well (as soon as you need that column used as a filter and/or search criteria)

And fill that field on insert/update where it is applicable.

This modification will increase performance of query where you should not use CAST and/or CONVERT for millions of records like you do here:

```
  AND CONVERT(`value_status`.`value`, SIGNED) >= 1
  AND (CONVERT(category_rgt.value, UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 2805 AND 4222)
```

So I have no more comments about structure.

But I would ask you to try my query, just like an experiment if it faster than yours. Unfortunately I have no possibility to debug  with any data. If you provide some sqlfiddle that will help a lot.

```
SELECT `company`.`id` AS `id`,
       `company`.`type` AS `type`
FROM `items` AS `company`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    item_id,
  FROM items_values
  WHERE name = 'status' 
       AND CONVERT(value, SIGNED) >= 1
) AS value_status
ON value_status.item_id = company.id

INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    lft_item_id
  FROM
    items_relationships 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      item_id
    FROM 
      items_values
    WHERE name = 'rgt'
      AND (CONVERT(value, UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 2805 AND 4222)
   ) AS category_rgt
  ON category_rgt.item_id = items_relationships.rgt_item_id
  WHERE items_relationships.rel_type = 'company_category'

) as companies_categories
ON (`companies_categories`.`lft_item_id` = `company`.`id`)

WHERE `company`.`type` = 'company'
GROUP BY `company`.`id`
ORDER BY `company`.`id` DESC 

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I've slightly improved design of `items_values` by creating extra column `value_index` type of `int` to prevent `CONVERT` and created new composed index on `name and value_index`. I will try the result